# circular ranked lists

Tags: ranking, circular-statistics, kendall-tau, concordance

I have two lists which are circular, in that given list

['A','B','C','D','E']

'A' and 'E' are the same distance apart as 'A' and 'B' and so on.

Given I have rankings

R1=['A','B','C','D','E']

R2=['E','A','B','C','D']

how can I compute their similarity or distance?

Comment: What are 'A','B','C','D','E'? Real numbers? Integers? Matrices?

Comment: they are categorical variables representing colors for example.

Answer (score 0):

The variables $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ can be encoded as points on a circle $S^1$ that is by angles between $0$ ans $2\pi$ if you measure the angles in radians. Vectors $R_1$ and $R_2$ are thus points on a five-dimensional torus $$T^5=\underbrace{S^1\times ...\times S^1}_\text{5}$$
The distance $d_{12}$ between $R_1$ and $R_2$ is the distance between these points on the torus $T^5$.

It's more convenient to measure the angles on your circles in $2\pi\cdot\mathrm{radians}$. Then  $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ are real numbers $x_1, ..., x_5$ all between $0$ and $1$. Then $R_1=(x_{11},..., x_{15})$, $R_2=(x_{21},..., x_{25})$, and

$$d_{12} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{5}s_i,$$
where 
\begin{equation}
  s_i =
    \begin{cases}
      |x_{2i}-x_{1i}|, & \text{if $|x_{2i}-x_{1i}|\leq 0.5$}\\
      1-|x_{2i}-x_{1i}|, & \text{if $|x_{2i}-x_{1i}| > 0.5$}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

An explanation of this formula for a two-dimensional torus is given here: [link](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/01/calculating-the-distance-between-points-in-wrap-around-toroidal-space/).